# Approve a PR as one CODEOWNER group but not another?

Tags: github, pull-request

My review has been requested on a GitHub PR. The PR touches two different modules:

- FooModule (needs review from `foo-reviewers`)
- BarModule (needs review from `bar-reviewers`)

I happen to be a member of both `foo-reviewers` and `bar-reviewers` but – for reasons – I only want to review FooModule right now and let others handle BarModule. But if I click the "Approve" button, it will mark the PR as approved by both groups.

Can I review this PR as only a `foo-reviewer`?